# Adding/Editing Node tab links through preprocess method

Tags: nodes, hooks, theming, views

When editing/adding/removing tab links to a Node page (View/Edit) is there a quick way doing this with a `hook_preprocess` method and not via creating a module to alter them? Such as using `hook_process_page()` and then editing the `$title_prefix` array since this is where they are stored.

Example: I created a module for editing the contextual links, but what if I wanted to skip creating a module and directly inject my changes in the `template.php` via  `hook()`.

```
function mymodule_contextual_links_view_alter(&$element, &$items) {
      $element['#links']['new-links'] = array(
        'title' => 'Add something new',
        'href' => url('/admin/config/add/something/new', array('absolute' => TRUE)),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `_alter()` hooks can be implemented by themes as well as modules, so in that specific case you can just use

```
function mytheme_contextual_links_view_alter(&$element, &$items) {
  ...
```

Comment: I see. What hook would you call to access the Node View/Edit tab links? Would it be something to do with the `$title_prefix` and using the `hook_preprocess_page()`? Thanks again for the info too.

Comment: You'd need to target the individual templates for those links (`hook_preprocess_node()`, `hook_preprocess_block()` maybe if that's applicable), but if the `$title_prefix` is structured in a way that you can alter then I say have at it

Comment: Ahhh ok. Think I'm getting close. Have another question but might need to open up a separate question for it. Thanks again for shining light on the direction!